# CLion not breaking on exceptions inside std lib (MinGW)

Tags: c++, mingw, clion

When my program causes the C++ standard library to throw an exception, the CLion debugger (with MinGW and gcc) does not stop upon the exception occuring. (My program is accessing a std::vector<> out of bounds somewhere.) Instead, the program and debugging session terminate, in my case with the following error in the console:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 2) >= this->size() (which is 2)
```

I have verified that I have "Exception Breakpoints" -> "When any is thrown" enabled in the Breakpoints view, and if I throw my own exception with `throw std::out_of_range("blah");`, the debugger does stop when it is thrown. How does one make CLion stop when an exception is thrown inside the standard library?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue, very frustrating.

Comment: Having the same issue with Linux/gcc